# Replacing values in JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, stringify

I have the following JSON object `data` returned from my apicontroller :

```
[  
  {"id":2,"text":"PROGRAMME","parent":null},
  {"id":3,"text":"STAGE","parent":2},
  {"id":4,"text":"INFRA","parent":2},
  {"id":5,"text":"SYSTEM","parent":3},
  {"id":6,"text":"STOCK","parent":3}, 
  {"id":7,"text":"DPT","parent":3},
  {"id":9,"text":"EXTERNAL","parent":null} 
]
```

I want to replace `"parent":null` with `"parent":'"#"'`

I have tried the code below, but it is only replacing the first occurrence of `"parent":null`. How can I replace all `"parent":null` entries?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:37994/api/EPStructures2/",
        type: "Get",
        success: function (data) {
            var old = JSON.stringify(data).replace(null, "'#'"); //convert to JSON string
            var new = JSON.parse(old); //convert back to array
        },
        error: function (msg) { alert(msg); }
    });
});
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to make the replace global:

```
var old = JSON.stringify(data).replace(/null/g, '"#"'); //convert to JSON string
var newArray = JSON.parse(old); //convert back to array
```

This way it will continue to replace nulls until it reaches the end

Regex docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

**Also, as a side note, you should avoid using `new` as a variable name as it is a reserved word in javascript and most browsers will not allow you to use it**

Comment: So obvious, although I was having trouble with this on my own. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

@JonathanCrowe's answer is correct for regex, but is that the right choice here? Particularly if you have many items, you'd be much better off modifying the parsed object, rather than running it through `JSON.stringify` for a regex solution:

```
data.forEach(function(record) {
    if (record.parent === null) {
        record.parent = "#";
    }
});
```

In addition to being faster, this won't accidentally replace other nulls you want to keep, or mess up a record like `{ text: "Denullification Program"}`.

Comment: Totally agree with this, if you are only looking to replace null "parent" keys then you are certainly better off with this approach to avoid any unwanted side effects

Comment: Even more concise in newer JS: `data.forEach(record => record.parent ||= '"#"')`