# How to remove colon based emojis from text using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, regex, string, emoji

How can i remove all instances of :smile: style emjois from a string using javascript? Here is an example below I got in JSON with :point_right: in it. I'd love to remove all of them from a string.

```
[ { service_name: 'Instagram',
   title: 'Instagram: “:point_right: Real people, making real products from real plants, using their actual hands to put them in boxes that show up on your doorstep.…”',
   text: '36 Likes, 2 Comments - “:point_right: Real people, making real products',
  ts: '1523497358.000299' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regular expression:

```js
const input = 'Instagram: “:point_right: Real people, making real products from real plants, using their actual hands to put them in boxes that show up on your doorstep.…”';

const output = input.replace(/:\w+:/g, '');

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the emojis are all one word, between `:`s:

```js
const obj = {
  service_name: 'Instagram',
  title: 'Instagram: “:point_right: Real people, making real products from real plants, using their actual hands to put them in boxes that show up on your doorstep.…”',
  text: '36 Likes, 2 Comments - “:point_right: Real people, making real products',
  ts: '1523497358.000299'
}

obj.title = obj.title.replace(/:[^ ]+:/g, '');
obj.text = obj.text.replace(/:[^ ]+:/g, '');
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

From this answer [Replacing values in JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639345/replacing-values-in-json-object) you could do this :

```js
var json=[ { service_name: 'Instagram',
   title: 'Instagram: “:point_right: Real people, making real products from real plants, using their actual hands to put them in boxes that show up on your doorstep.…”',
   text: '36 Likes, 2 Comments - “:point_right: Real people, making real products',
  ts: '1523497358.000299' }];

var rep = JSON.stringify(json).replace(/(“)(:[^:]+:)/g, '$1'); 
var New = JSON.parse(rep); 
console.log(New);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
// JSON Object
var jsonObj = [{
 "service_name": "Instagram",
 "title": "Instagram: “:point_right: Real people, making real products from real plants, using their actual hands to put them in boxes that show up on your doorstep.…”",
 "text": "36 Likes, 2 Comments - “:point_right: Real people, making real products",
 "ts": "1523497358.000299"
}];

// Replace :point_right: with blank string.
jsonObj.map(obj => {
  obj.title = obj.title.replace(":point_right: ", "");
  obj.text = obj.text.replace(":point_right: ", "");
  return obj;
});

// Output
console.log(jsonObj);
```